# problem on similar triangles

Tags: geometry

> In the adjacent figure, $\frac{AG}{GD} = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{4}{7}$ and $AE=12 $ cm. Find the length of $EC$.
>   1) 33
>   2) 36
>   3) 44
>   4) 48

Figure:
 [image]
I think similarity of triangles is to be used but can't really find the target triangles.

Comment: For what it's worth, GD is to AD as BD is to DC. So triangles BGD and ADC may be involved.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If we consider triangles BGD and ADC then as per given ratios we should have AC is to BG will be equal to 7/4 but again BG is unknown so we cant find Ac and hence can't find AE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Menelaus' Theorem
$$\frac{BD}{BC}.\frac{CE}{AE}.\frac{AG}{GD}=1\Rightarrow\frac{4}{11}.\frac{CE}{12}.\frac{3}{4}=1$$

Comment: But BD/BC, CE/AC, and AG/GD can all be less than 1, so I don't see how their product can be 1. Have you quoted the theorem correctly?

Comment: Yes, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem.html

Comment: @user1772257 this theorem that you have mentioned does give 44 which is one of the options.(I don't know the correct answer for this question). However it's not in scope of my study.

Comment: Great, but, what about my objection? three numbers, each less than 1, can't multiply to 1, no matter what mathworld might say. Also, in the statement of the question, AE is given as 12, but in your calculation, you've taken AC as 12.

Comment: Look at the diagram. $AC=AE+CE\gt CE$.

Comment: Ah! You've changed it! So, do you still claim your original quote was right?

Comment: Suy, you can see how Menelaus is proved at, say, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus'_theorem and then use the reasoning without quoting the theorem.

Comment: No, there was a typo in the first quote.

Comment: Is there no other way like through similarity or something?

Comment: This question should not be requiring any application of any advanced theorems.

Comment: Suy, did you look at the proof of the Menelaus theorem? Do you understand my comment that you can use the reasoning of the proof without using the theorem?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks I got it.